# What is the difference between ERL and EA by considering it as RL?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, evolutionary-algorithms

I am currently studying as an MSCS student and my research is based on Evolutionary Algorithm as Reinforcement Learning, and I am confused about the following terms:

1. What is the difference between Evolutionary Reinforcement Learning and Evolutionary Algorithm by considering it as Reinforcement Learning?
2. if the Evolutionary Algorithm is Reinforcement Learning, what's the definition of state?
3. which part of the Evolutionary Algorithm is the rewards of Reinforcement Learning?
4. What will be the transition and Action function? can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE. It seems you're asking many questions. Please, [**ask only 1 question per post**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224). Before providing an answer, you should provide more context. For example, where did you find the term "evolutionary RL"? So, I suggest that you split this post into 4  (one for each of your questions), and, for each of these posts, provide the necessary context to understand the problem. It may also be a good idea to explain what problem you're trying to solve with "Evolutionary Algorithm as Reinforcement Learning" (whatever that is).

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your response ok I'll follow your suggestion I'll spill this post into four parts but if it is possible can you please guide me for only one question which is What is the difference between Evolutionary Reinforcement Learning and Evolutionary Algorithm by considering it as Reinforcement Learning?

Comment: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/majumdar20a/majumdar20a.pdf

Comment: Please, edit your post to leave only one main specific question and make it clear which one it is.